# Remote Login from the greeter not working

Tags: 13.04, login

I'm trying to set up the `Remote Login` feature of Ubuntu, but I can't get it to work.

I've created an Ubuntu One account, connected to `uccs.landscape.canonical.com`, logged in using the aforementioned Ubuntu One account, and added 4 remote desktop logins.

However, when I try and login by clicking `Remote Login` from the greeter, and then enter my Ubuntu One email address and password, I'm told there is an error with either one of those details.

Can anyone please shed any light as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out here that Ubuntu 13.04 does not come with one particular package that is require for remote logons.

Enter this code in the Terminal and then the feature will work correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pycurl
```

Comment: It won't let me yet, you have to wait 2 days!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know.